# jQuery UI images css

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-ui, themes, jquery-ui-theme

Can I get the images used in the self created theme direct or do I have to cut them out from the `"\jquery-ui-themeroller\theme\images\ui-icons_228ef1_256x240.png"` for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that you could probably download the themeroller 1.5 version of the theme and it would have them.  Thats currently not working though.

http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4089